# Optimization for: while (true)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break, infinite

I'm using a

```
while (true)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

loop like so, the frame is just an example frame, as the actual code itself is convoluted and overly complicated that it requires a "break;" statement in multiple different areas for multiple different conditions.
My question is; Is there a way to write a loop statement without the loop checking for a condition at all? Is there a more efficient way to write an infinite loop other than while(true)?

edit: (java)

edit2:

```
while (a < b)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (c < d)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                //do alot of stuff
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        else if (d > c)
        {
            if (e == null)
            {
                //do alot of stuff
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        else if (d == c)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    a = a + 1;
}
```

Comment: That depends on the actual circumstances. The example you give is easily simplified to `while (x != y) {// do stuff}`. But I assume, your real case is more comlicated.

Comment: I'll post the actual circumstances, in a comment edit.

Comment: Efficiency of the outer loop hardly matters if there's a lot of code inside it. You don't need `else` after `break`, and therefore you don't need the code controlled by the `else` to be inside `{}` and indented.You also don't need to test `d == c` after having already tested `d < c` and `d > c`. Attention to this sort of thing alone would simplify the look of your code considerably.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to write a loop statement without the loop checking for a condition at all? Is there a more efficient way to write an infinite loop other than while(true)?

You can write an infinite loop in multiple ways, but they are all equivalent. Neither is really more efficient than the others:

1. `while (true) { ... }`
2. `do { ... } while (true);`
3. `for (;;) { ... }`

Depending on the actual code, it may make sense to **reverse the "break-loop-logic" into "continue-loop-logic",** as in:

```
boolean continueLoop;
do {
    continueLoop = false;

    // ... do stuff ...

    if ( some condition ) {
        continueLoop = true;
    }

    // ... do stuff ...

} while (continueLoop);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example, you may move the logic for breaking in the `if` statement to the `while` condition:

```
while (x != y) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In fact, if your original `while` loop had multiple conditions for breaking, you might be able to move them all to the `while` condition, e.g.

```
while (!cond1 && !cond2 ... ) {
    // execute
}
```

Comment: While that second example may work, I often find that in such cases, the values of `cond{i}` change during loop body execution, often before they are evaluated to trigger a break.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I'm speculating of course, because we don't know the OP's actual code (and get ready when we find out it is much more complex).  I agree with your comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a lot ways you can do this. For example you can declare a variable outside a loop put a condition based on variable value  and  reset that variable inside a loop, hence loop will run infinitely without checking internal conditions.

Read this for examples :-
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop

Comment: `for(;;)` is something useful I found in wiki

Comment: @Saharsh There is no practical difference between `while (true)` and `for (;;)`.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I went back to wiki and realized how comment says its equivalent to `while(1)`